# Concat string with return column in SELECT in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Please see code.

```
return from org in context.Organizations
                   select new
                   {
                       PlaceId = org.OrganizationId,
                       org.Name
                   };
```

How to concat some string with Name in above query, like

```
return from org in context.Organizations
                   select new
                   {
                       PlaceId = org.OrganizationId,
                       org.Name + "Some string will go here" // Error: How to do this
                   };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe?

```
select new
{
    PlaceId = org.OrganizationId,
    Name = org.Name + "Some string will go here" // Error: How to do this
};
```